# Simple Question: How to Load corpora (.txt files) in R

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus

*Context:* I have 47 .txt files which are all technically small corpora. They have been lowercased and full-stops have been removed.

*Question*: Would anyone know how to or be able to point me to a resource that explains how to load these in R? I wish to lemmatise them and extract collocations (nearest neighbours) within a term with a window size of 3 + their counts per corpus + proportion (count of collocate/ total tokens in corpus).

Any resources/ tips would be much appreciated. It might be a simple solution. I am completely new to handling corpus data, but have tried the below code so far which did not work:

```
corpus <- load.corpus("corpus1.txt")
```

Comment: [This is a resource](https://rstatisticsblog.com/text-mining/perfect-guide-to-basic-text-processing-in-r/) which explains how to do standard preprocessing. Extracting colocations with a sliding window is more advanced, I don't know if there's a library so you might have to code it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Erwan!